# What is the different between the Google Guava math methods like checkedAdd(a,b) versus the addExact() method in the Math class?

Tags: java, guava

com.google.common.math

vs.

java.lang.Math

Same parameters and same return type. What's the difference?

Comment: Nothing. One just predates the other

Comment: Yeah Java 8+ took many ideas from Guava, which came earlier. Overall you're better off using the Java standard versions.